# Unity 2D Renderer URP Makes my UI Camera have a background color

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I am trying to add lighting to my 2D project, so I created a new Universal Render Pipeline that takes in a 2D renderer. I have 2 separate cameras, one for UI, and one for game elements. The moment I add a pipeline to my project, my UI Camera has a background color, although the clear flags are set to depth only.

What I've tried so far:
Turning of Post-Processing, did not work.
Camera stacking, but it is not available on the 2D Renderer, according to the docs.
Making the camera background color transparent, but the Alpha channel does not seem to affect the color in any way.
The unity version I m working on is 2019.3.4f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. So just in case anyone runs to this problem in the future, make sure you have the latest version of the URP on the package manager, then you will have the option to use camera stacking which works just fine for this case.